# Postfix requeing missed message to be processed by milter

Tags: email, postfix

I have a situation where we missed configuring smtpd_milters in main.cf, but lots of emails have come in and stored at /var/spool/postfix/deferred queue.  Now that I have fixed the smtpd_milters in the postfix configuration, I want those emails that have already stored in deferred queue to be processed by milter.   Is there anyway to achieve it?  I tried moving those files around to incoming, active etc., but not helping.  Any help here would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The mail must be resubmitted through smtpd.

To do so, first get the queue ID of the mail you want to reprocess.

```
mailq
```

Place the original message on hold

```
postsuper -h [QUEUEID]
```

Extract the email message

```
postcat -qbh [QUEUEID] > /tmp/email.eml
```

Resubmit the mail

```
cat /tmp/email.eml | sendmail -t
```

Check your queues and log output to ensure the mail was sent correctly, afterwards you may delete the original message.

```
postsuper -d [QUEUEID]
```

Comment: The chances of the original submitter approving this answer after 7 years are slim, but I'm leaving this answer because I landed on this page and then found the solution. Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are running `postfix`, you can try the command:

```
postqueue -f
```

This will cause postfix to flush the queue and attempt to deliver all queued messages. Alternatively, you can use:

```
postqueue -i <queue_id>
```

to schedule immediate delivery of the message identified by `<queue_id>`. that way you can try out your milter settings before actually flushing the entire queue. You can read more about `postqueue` on the [postqueue documentation page](http://www.postfix.org/postqueue.1.html).

Comment: Milters are not applied on a requeue.